# Got a DBus::Path with libdbus-c++ - what next?

Tags: c++, ipc, dbus

I have a short test program I am using to work out how to use D-Bus with the `libdbus-c++` library. I am trying to connect to the `wpa_supplicant` D-Bus API (documented [here](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html#dbus_interface)) in order to read a list of WiFi APs and their strengths.

Following [this guide](http://blog.emilienkia.net/en/?post/2012/11/07/Journey-into-the-world-of-DBus-for-C-%28part-2%29-attempt-around-libdbus-c), I have generated a proxy header with `dbusxx-xml2cpp wpa_supplicant_dbus_service.xml --proxy=proxy.h` and implemented a `WPAS` class with stub handlers for the signals:

```
class WPAS : public fi::w1::wpa_supplicant1_proxy,
                    public DBus::IntrospectableProxy,
                    public DBus::ObjectProxy
{
public:
     WPAS(DBus::Connection &connection, const char *path, const char *name):
     DBus::ObjectProxy(connection, path, name)
     {
     }

    void InterfaceAdded(const ::DBus::Path& path, const std::map< std::string, ::DBus::Variant >& properties) {}
    void InterfaceRemoved(const ::DBus::Path& path) {}
    void PropertiesChanged(const std::map< std::string, ::DBus::Variant >& properties) {}
};
```

The rest of the code looks like this:

```
#include <dbus-c++/dbus.h>
#include "proxy.h"

DBus::BusDispatcher dispatcher;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DBus::default_dispatcher = &dispatcher;
    DBus::Connection bus = DBus::Connection::SystemBus();

    DBus::Path path;

    WPAS wpad(bus, "/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1", "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1");

    path = wpad.GetInterface("wlan2");

    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't know what to do next. The aim is to call the `Scan()` method of `fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface`.

Answer (score 0):

It follow a similar pattern to how you call `fi::w1::wpa_supplicant1.GetInterface`; i.e. I would create another class (e.g. `WPASI`) that inherits from `fi::w1::wpa_supplicant1::Interface_proxy`, `DBus::IntrospectableProxy` and `DBus::ObjectProxy`.

Assuming that both objects (wpad and the interface) are on the same service, you would create an instance of this new class as follows:

```
WPASI wpasi( bus, path, "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1" );
```

Then just call `wpasi.Scan()` as usual.